# Chrome Extension, Determine if a link will return a 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a functionality in my chrome extension where I can provide a link and it will try to navigate to that link. If the link returns a 302 redirection, it will try again until it does not redirect. How would I go about doing this? I could not find anything about tabs returning a status. An alternative that I could do is to actually go to the URL and look at the URL at the time of document.ready, but I feel this will be much slower.

Comment: You could always make a `HEAD` request, but not all servers implement this.

Comment: Why do you want to implement something like this? Browsers will automatically follow 302s.. And further, 302 redirects are meant to be temporary, so automatically following them AND storing the redirect makes no sense.

Comment: Because I don't want to follow the redirect. I basically want to go to the real URL that won't redirect as soon as I can. To do so, I want to attempt to go to the URL and if it redirects, cancel and try again.